# How do I get value of input field in React, if I am using Material Ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design

I have few radio inputs which are imported from material Ui react components,

```
      <FormControlLabel onClick={checkAnswerHandler} value={answer} control={<Radio color="primary" />} label={<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer}}></span>} />
</div>
```

Here, I tried to access the value of input through onClick function like below

```
const checkAnswer = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
 
     answer = e.currentTarget.value; //but throws error as label is not an input element
     
  }
```

so, How do I get the Value of input tag cause I am unable to implement **onClick function** to input tag?

Comment: This all a bit confusing to me. Where does `answer` come from? You seem to want to reassign it and it's not clear to me why. Is `checkAnswerHandler` somehow related to `checkAnswer`? Can you post your entire component (or all relevant parts)?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value from `RadioGroup`

look at this example from Matrial-ui documentation:

```html
<FormControl component="fieldset">
  <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
  <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
    <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
    <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
    <FormControlLabel value="disabled" disabled control={<Radio />} label="(Disabled option)" />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Although I tried applying your solution, but I get value as 'undefined' can you fix it?

Comment: take a look: https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#ErrorRadios.js